# Unable to sort bars by value in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, forcats

I have tried everything to sort my bars in geom(bar) in ggplot by spending. This is my code:
I have tried manually ordering the data, forcats, changing as an aes in ggplot and can't get it to work.

```
#Load any packages 
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(janitor)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(forcats)

#Create data frame
MarketSize <- data.frame(Country = c("United States", "Japan", "Germany", "France", "Italy", "United Kingdom", "Spain", "Canada", "South Korea",
                                     "Australia", "China", "Brazil", "Russia", "India", "Other"),
                            Spending_2020 = c(528.7, 88.2, 54.9, 36.3, 33.3, 30.2, 25.7, 22.8, 16.2, 11.8, 134.4, 28.7, 17.5, 21.5, 15)
)

# Arrange by Spending outside ggplot
MarketSize$Country <- fct_rev(fct_infreq(MarketSize$Country))

#Create plot, labels etc.
MarketSize_2020 <- ggplot(MarketSize, aes(x = Country, y = Spending_2020)) + 
  geom_col(fill="steelblue", width=0.75) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Spending_2020), vjust=0.5, hjust=-0.01, size=3.5) +
  coord_flip() +
  labs(title = "Market Spending on pharmaceuticals, 2020",
       x = "Country or region",
       y = "Total spending on pharmaceuticals (US $BN)") +
  theme_classic() 

#View plot
MarketSize_2020
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance

I have tried ordering using forcats package and cannot get it to work!

Comment: Try with `MarketSize$Country <- fct_reorder(MarketSize$Country, MarketSize$Spending_2020)`

Comment: Thanks so much @stefan, worked straight away!